# How many ways are there to arrange $5$ artists and $5$ writers in a circle such that artists and writers alternate subject to the stated condition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have query regarding arrangement of 5 artists and 5 writers.  They are to be arranged in a circle such that they are alternating.  In how many ways this can be done if two particular artists must not sit next to a particular writer.

I first tried to find the number of linear arrangement and then divide by the number of elements.  However, my answer is not correct.

Comment: This might help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795857/how-many-ways-are-there-to-order-n-women-and-n-men-in-circle?rq=1

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the particular difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming unnumbered seats, as is usual unless specified otherwise, and that the arrangements are to be counted under rotation.

Put the "unwanted" writer at the north position. Positions adjacent can be "properly" filled in $3\cdot2$ ways by artists, and the remaining artists and writers can be put in 3!4! ways maintaining alternate types,

Thus $3\cdot2\cdot 4!3! = 864$ ways

Comment: Have you understood the answer ??